# Grails 2.2.1 and IntelliJ. Application template files (_*.gsp) not getting recompiled and need a server restart

Tags: grails, intellij-idea

I am using grails 2.2.1 and IntelliJ IDEA 14 for development. During development, when *.gsp files are changed, they get recompiled and loaded but not template files (_*.gsp). Is there a way I can get this working? Appreciate any reply.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question may have already been answered. Check out this post on the [Grails reloading configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1325734/grails-auto-reload-functionality-in-run-app-on-a-custom-environment). You will want to edit your config.groovy file with something like the following.

```
disable.auto.recompile=false
grails.gsp.enable.reload=true
```